# Python script is not executing with PHP

Tags: php, python

Python command doesn't showing any result. It just showing Blank.

whoami command is running successfully.
But there is some problem with python.

PHP:

```
<?php

echo 'before<br />';

$my_command = escapeshellcmd('whoami');
$command_output = shell_exec($my_command);
echo $command_output;

echo '<br />&nbsp;New Command<br />';

$my_command = escapeshellcmd('python test.py');
$command_output = shell_exec($my_command);
echo $command_output;

?>
```

Python:

```
echo "Hello World"
```

Comment: _Please help me as soon as possible..._ Please avoid using such statements

Comment: Are you running that PHP script through a web server or using command line? If you're using a web server, make sure that the web servers user (on Apache, it's typically www-data) has permission to execute that script. And that it finds the `python`-command. You might need to use an absolute path (since web server users usually don't have the same environment paths as normal users).

Comment: `echo "Hello World"` is not valid Python code. That is a syntax error in any version of Python.

Answer (score 0):

Use this: (`2>&1` in `shell_exec`)

```
$command_output = shell_exec('python path\test.py 2>&1');
echo $command_output;
```

`>&` is the syntax to redirect a stream to another file descriptor - `0` is stdin, `1` is stdout, and `2` is stderr.

`2` refers to the second file descriptor of the process, i.e. stderr.

`>` means redirection.

`&1` means the target of the redirection should be the same location as the first file descriptor, i.e. stdout.

Comment: Don't escape the command and pass the path of the file as well.

Answer (score 0):

I tested your code. Your php code works, it's the python code which is wrong.

Replace the content of `test.py` with:

```
print("Hello World")
```

if you use python3, or:

```
print "Hello World"
```

if you use python2.

If you run your php script from command line (`php myfile.php`) you would have seen the invalid sintax error raised by the python interpreter.
As you probably run your script on your server, you should check the error logs to see the error. Error log position depends on your server, for example on my apache 2 localhost server is at `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.